# Не могу решить задание

Tags: python

Я участвую в школьной олимпиаде, и совсем не могу решить последнее задание.

Вот условие задачи:

Чтобы легче передавать информацию устно, они называют последовательность символов A, G, T, C «читаемой», если рядом ни с одной согласной нет другой согласной, а рядом ни с одной гласной — другой гласной, и предпочитают работать только с такими последовательностями.

Дано число N. Сколько различных читаемых последовательностей длины N существует? Так как ответ может быть очень большим, выведите остаток от его деления на 10^9 + 7.

Но также есть ограничение на время исполнения(1 секунда)

вот одна из моих попыток написать что-то

```
import string
import random, re
N=10
words= [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(N)]
st_r = ""
word=(str_r.join(words))
glasniye = len(re.findall(r'[AEIOUY]', word))
soglasniye = len(re.findall(r'[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]', word))
```

До этой олимпиады никогда не писал на питоне.

Comment: Если можно, то покажите как надо написать, я смогу разобраться как это работает.

Comment: Приведите условие текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас приведу. Спасибо!

Comment: О, вы уже третий за последние пару дней с этой задачей. И опять зачем-то не относящиеся к задаче буквы алфавита перечисляете.

Comment: Правда? 
Ну задача сложная, как по мне. Я пытался написать рабочий код, но не понимаю как определить позицию стоящих рядом букв

Comment: Не надо никакие позиции определять, и генерировать строки не надо. Требуется вывести формулу для количества и посчитать по ней.

Comment: А как примерно должна выглядеть/начинаться эта формула? Я не совсем понимаю

Comment: очень просто выглядит формула. Начни с простого. Сколько последовательностей длины 1 существует? Сколько длины 2? Как по последней букве в последовательности можно определить, какие буквы могут быть следующими?

Comment: Так там ведь и длина, и буквы могут быть совершенно случайны

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452113/%d0%9e%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0

Comment: Длина-  входной  параметр. Буквы в условии перечислены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте выведем формулу для чётной длины.
Если строка начинается с `"A"`, то она имеет вид `A*A*A*A*`, где вместо звёздочек стоят любые из символов `"G","C","T"`.
При длине `N` в строке `N//2` мест для этих согласных.
Для каждого места есть три варианта, итого таких строк `3**N//2`.
Аналогично для случая, когда строка начинается с согласной `*A*A*A*A`. Итого `2*3**N//2` вариантов.

Осталось сделать подобные вычисления для нечётной длины - строки вида `А*A*A*A` и `*A*A*A*`

Comment: Спасибо за направление в правильное русло, разберусь как это работает!